# Перенос всех переменных в другую область видимости

Tags: php

Есть локальная область видимости и родительская. Необходимо в локальной получить все возможные переменные из родительской.В этом случае замыкания или глобалс не проходит.Возможно ли это сделать?

Comment: Что имеется в виду под родительской областью видимости? Базовый класс? Есть возможность привести пример?

Comment: @cheops Тут все просто.Есть некая функция,простая. И есть просто изначальная область видимости.(родительская, которая нам даётся при запуске скрипта)

Comment: Вы можете получить только содержимое глобальной области видимости. Если родительская область !== глобальная, то ничего сделать не получится. К тому же, кмк, вы пытаетесь реализовать чудовищный костыль.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, можно передать возвращаемый функцией get_defined_vars() массив со списком переменных глобальной области видимости.

```
<?php
  $var = 'hello';
  function func($all_variables) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($all_variables);
    echo "</pre>";
  }
  func(get_defined_vars());
```

или передать этот список через globals или замыкание.

Функция get_defined_vars() удобна тем, что берет переменные текущей области видимости, поэтому это сработает не только для глобальной области.

Comment: Алгоритм такой:  получаем список - кидаем на функцию - получаем и каждую обрабатываем через массив $_GLOBALS?Так как я не понимаю как можно это сделать через обычную конструкцию globals.Кроме как если globals $_GLOBALS[]

Comment: Можно просто объявить свой массив $all_vars = get_defined_vars(), а в функции $all_vars объявить глобальным через globals.

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо использовать конструкцию `use`:

```
$globalScope = get_defined_vars();

$callback = function() use ($globalScope) {
   $globalScope;
}
```

Далее вы успользуете эту анонимную функцию где-то. Более подрбная информация тут: http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.anonymous.php (пример #3)